# Parse Nested JsonArray manually

Tags: android, arrays, parsing

```html
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.sam.makeanoffer, PID: 13067
                                                   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                       at com.sam.makeanoffer.adapters.PinnedListAdapter.getView(PinnedListAdapter.java:78)
                                                       at com.sam.makeanoffer.pinnedlistLib.AdapterWrapper.getView(AdapterWrapper.java:154)
                                                       at com.sam.makeanoffer.pinnedlistLib.AdapterWrapper.getView(AdapterWrapper.java:16)
                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2367)
                                                       at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1972)
                                                       at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
                                                       at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:765)
                                                       at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1716)
                                                       at com.sam.makeanoffer.pinnedlistLib.WrapperViewList.layoutChildren(WrapperViewList.java:193)
                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2161)
                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
                                                       at com.sam.makeanoffer.pinnedlistLib.StickyListHeadersListView.onLayout(StickyListHeadersListView.java:265)
                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
                                                       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
                                                       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17535)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5616)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2354)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2081)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1258)
                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6348)
                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

I'm using PinnedSectionListView which has a custom layout for header as well as child. The problem I'm facing here is that all child layouts gets attached to first header while the second header does not shows. In my jsonarray I've 2 headers and each have single child. I tried to debug the code and found that the 'j' for loop is working twice without going to the 'i' for loop. That's why both child layouts gets attached to the first header.

```js
public class PinnedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements StickyListHeadersAdapter, SectionIndexer {

    private final Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<HeaderModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<ChildModel> childList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static int prepos=-1;
    private SharedPref pref;

    public PinnedListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HeaderModel> arrayList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.childList = childList;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        pref = new SharedPref(mContext);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.multicartchildrow, parent, false);
            holder.myimage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myimage);
            holder.titletxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titletxt);
            holder.qtytxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qtytxt);
            holder.pricetxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pricetxt);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ChildModel model = arrayList.get(position).getChildList().get(position);
        //ChildModel model = childList.get(position);

        holder.titletxt.setText(model.getChildtitle());
        holder.qtytxt.setText(model.getChildqty());
        holder.pricetxt.setText(pref.getString(Utility.CURRENCY)+" "+model.getChildprice());
        Glide.with(mContext).load(model.getChildimage()).dontAnimate().into(holder.myimage);


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getHeaderView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final HeaderViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new HeaderViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.multicartheaderrow, parent, false);
            holder.RL_root = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RL_root);
            holder.image = (CircleImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.nametxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nametxt);
            holder.select = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.select);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (HeaderViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final HeaderModel model = arrayList.get(position);

        holder.nametxt.setText(model.getHeadertext());
        Glide.with(mContext).load(model.getHeaderimage()).dontAnimate().into(holder.image);



        holder.select.setTag(position);

        /*holder.select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                if(isChecked) {
                    //holder.select.setChecked(true);
                    model.setChecked(true);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else{
                    //holder.select.setChecked(false);
                    model.setChecked(false);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        });*/

        System.out.println("sammy_position "+position);
        System.out.println("sammy_prepos "+prepos);

        if(position == prepos){
            holder.select.setChecked(true);
            pref.setString(Utility.MULTI_SELLLER_ID, model.getHeaderid());


        }else{
            holder.select.setChecked(false);
        }


        holder.select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                holder.select.setChecked(true);

                if(holder.select.isChecked()){
                    prepos = position;
                }else{
                    prepos = -1;
                }


                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });



        return convertView;
    }

    /**
     * Remember that these have to be static, postion=1 should always return
     * the same Id that is.
     */
    @Override
    public long getHeaderId(int position) {
        // return the first character of the country as ID because this is what
        // headers are based upon
        return arrayList.get(position).getHeadertext().subSequence(0, 1).charAt(0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        return null;
    }

    /*public void clear() {
        mCountries = new String[0];
        mSectionIndices = new int[0];
        mSectionLetters = new Character[0];
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void restore() {
        mCountries = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);
        mSectionIndices = getSectionIndices();
        mSectionLetters = getSectionLetters();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }*/

    class HeaderViewHolder {
        RelativeLayout RL_root;
        CircleImageView image;
        TextView nametxt;
        CheckBox select;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView myimage;
        TextView titletxt, qtytxt, pricetxt;
    }

}
```

```css
{
  "all_cart_products": [
    {
      "seller_id": "1",
      "seller_name": "Supriya ghosh",
      "email": "abc@gmail.com",
      "seller_image": "http:\/\/www.example.com\/upload\/userimage\/1493023436_ajeet_1000016806.jpg",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "9",
          "product_user_id": "1",
          "name": "antique5",
          "desc": "Scads dsvdjkshvdsv dsvjhdsvdsv dsjkvhdjksvds vdskhjvndsvd svdjshnvjkdsv dsvkdjsh",
          "quantity": "1",
          "unit_price": "3200.00",
          "total_price1": 3200,
          "total_price": "3200.00",
          "itemImage": "http:\/\/www.example.com\/upload\/product\/1492757990myprod.jpg",
          "totalquantity": "99"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "seller_id": "3",
      "seller_name": "Somnath Pal",
      "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
      "seller_image": "http:\/\/www.example.com\/upload\/userimage\/1492766252IMG_20150325_174836~3.jpg",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "44",
          "product_user_id": "3",
          "name": "Roses",
          "desc": "fresh flowers",
          "quantity": "0",
          "unit_price": "26.00",
          "total_price1": 0,
          "total_price": "0.00",
          "itemImage": "http:\/\/www.example.com\/upload\/product\/1493017537myprod.jpg",
          "totalquantity": "100"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "total_qty": 0,
  "Ack": 1
}
```

```html
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Utility.GETFULLCART,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        pd.dismiss();

                        System.out.println("sammy_MultiCartActivity_getAllCartProducts_response "+response);
                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            if(jObj.getInt("Ack")==1){
                                JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("all_cart_products");
System.out.println("sammy_headerArray "+jsonArray.length());                                
                                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject main = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    JSONArray jarr = main.getJSONArray("products");
  System.out.println("sammy_childArray "+jarr.length());                                  for(int j=0; j<jarr.length(); j++){

                                        JSONObject obj = jarr.getJSONObject(j);

                                        ChildModel childModel = new ChildModel();
                                        childModel.setChildimage(obj.getString("itemImage"));
                                        childModel.setChildtitle(obj.getString("name"));
                                        childModel.setChildqty(obj.getString("quantity"));
                                        childModel.setChildprice(obj.getString("total_price"));
                                        childList.add(childModel);
                                    }

                                    HeaderModel model = new HeaderModel();
                                    model.setHeaderimage(main.getString("seller_image"));
                                    model.setHeadertext(main.getString("seller_name"));
                                    model.setHeaderid(main.getString("seller_id"));
                                    model.setChildList(childList);
                                    arrayList.add(model);




                                }
                            }

                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            pd.dismiss();
                            // JSON error
                            System.out.println("sammy_JSONError "+e);
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                pd.dismiss();
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    Toast.makeText(MultiCartActivity.this,getString(R.string.tooslow),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                    Toast.makeText(MultiCartActivity.this,getString(R.string.nointernet),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    System.out.println("sammy_AuthFailureError "+error);
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    System.out.println("sammy_ServerError "+error);
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    System.out.println("sammy_NetworkError "+error);
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    System.out.println("sammy_ParseError "+error);
                }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("user_id", pref.getString(Utility.USERID));
                System.out.println("sammy_MultiCartActivity_getAllCartProducts_params "+params);
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MultiCartActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                10000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    }
```

Comment: why do you try to parse it Manually? You have GSON for this!!!You are working too hard i think

Comment: I'm trying to understand the logic for header and child list. And parsing manually will give me certain explanation. Besides I've never used GSON as it needs model class. Could you let me know if I'm parsing it wrong somewhere?

Comment: everything looks fine.. try to check the length of two arrays.

Comment: Length also coming correctly 2 and 1.

Comment: make yourself a favor and switch to GSON

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems OK. I have tried it myself and its working. See my `output` below.

**CLEAN** and **RUN** your `project` again.

**Here is the working code:**

```
public void parseJson() {
    // Your JSON
    String response = "{\n" +
            "  \"all_cart_products\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"seller_id\": \"1\",\n" +
            "      \"seller_name\": \"Supriya ghosh\",\n" +
            "      \"email\": \"abc@gmail.com\",\n" +
            "      \"seller_image\": \"http:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/upload\\/userimage\\/1493023436_ajeet_1000016806.jpg\",\n" +
            "      \"products\": [\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "          \"id\": \"9\",\n" +
            "          \"product_user_id\": \"1\",\n" +
            "          \"name\": \"antique5\",\n" +
            "          \"desc\": \"Scads dsvdjkshvdsv dsvjhdsvdsv dsjkvhdjksvds vdskhjvndsvd svdjshnvjkdsv dsvkdjsh\",\n" +
            "          \"quantity\": \"1\",\n" +
            "          \"unit_price\": \"3200.00\",\n" +
            "          \"total_price1\": 3200,\n" +
            "          \"total_price\": \"3200.00\",\n" +
            "          \"itemImage\": \"http:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/upload\\/product\\/1492757990myprod.jpg\",\n" +
            "          \"totalquantity\": \"99\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "      ]\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"seller_id\": \"3\",\n" +
            "      \"seller_name\": \"Somnath Pal\",\n" +
            "      \"email\": \"xyz@gmail.com\",\n" +
            "      \"seller_image\": \"http:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/upload\\/userimage\\/1492766252IMG_20150325_174836~3.jpg\",\n" +
            "      \"products\": [\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "          \"id\": \"44\",\n" +
            "          \"product_user_id\": \"3\",\n" +
            "          \"name\": \"Roses\",\n" +
            "          \"desc\": \"fresh flowers\",\n" +
            "          \"quantity\": \"0\",\n" +
            "          \"unit_price\": \"26.00\",\n" +
            "          \"total_price1\": 0,\n" +
            "          \"total_price\": \"0.00\",\n" +
            "          \"itemImage\": \"http:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/upload\\/product\\/1493017537myprod.jpg\",\n" +
            "          \"totalquantity\": \"100\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "      ]\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  ],\n" +
            "  \"total_qty\": 0,\n" +
            "  \"Ack\": 1\n" +
            "}";


    try {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

        if(jObj.getInt("Ack") == 1) {

            JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("all_cart_products");
            System.out.println("sammy_headerArray " + jsonArray.length());

            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject main = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONArray jarr = main.getJSONArray("products");
                System.out.println("sammy_childArray " + jarr.length());

                for(int j = 0; j < jarr.length(); j++){

                    JSONObject obj = jarr.getJSONObject(j);

                    String itemImage = obj.getString("itemImage");
                    String ItemName = obj.getString("name");
                    String quantity = obj.getString("quantity");
                    String totalPrice = obj.getString("total_price");

                    Log.d("SUCCESS", "PRODUCT: " + "\nImage: " + itemImage + "\nName: " + ItemName +
                            "\nQuantity: " + quantity + "\nTotal Price: " + totalPrice);

                    /*ChildModel childModel = new ChildModel();
                    childModel.setChildimage(obj.getString("itemImage"));
                    childModel.setChildtitle(obj.getString("name"));
                    childModel.setChildqty(obj.getString("quantity"));
                    childModel.setChildprice(obj.getString("total_price"));
                    childList.add(childModel);*/
                }

                String sellerImage = main.getString("seller_image");
                String sellerName = main.getString("seller_name");
                String sellerId = main.getString("seller_id");

                Log.d("SUCCESS", "SELLER: " + "\nSeller Image: " + sellerImage + "\nSeller Name: " + sellerName +
                        "\nSeller Id: " + sellerId);

                /*HeaderModel model = new HeaderModel();
                model.setHeaderimage(main.getString("seller_image"));
                model.setHeadertext(main.getString("seller_name"));
                model.setHeaderid(main.getString("seller_id"));
                model.setChildList(childList);
                arrayList.add(model);*/

            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // JSON error
        System.out.println("sammy_JSONError " + e);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

You didn't clear `childList` before `inserting` new seller `childs`.

**Try this:**

```
................
...........................

childList.clear()
for(int j = 0; j < jarr.length(); j++){
}

.............
......................
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
I/System.out: sammy_headerArray 2
I/System.out: sammy_childArray 1
D/SUCCESS: PRODUCT: 
           Image: http://www.example.com/upload/product/1492757990myprod.jpg
           Name: antique5
           Quantity: 1
           Total Price: 3200.00
D/SUCCESS: SELLER: 
           Seller Image: http://www.example.com/upload/userimage/1493023436_ajeet_1000016806.jpg
           Seller Name: Supriya ghosh
           Seller Id: 1

I/System.out: sammy_childArray 1
D/SUCCESS: PRODUCT: 
           Image: http://www.example.com/upload/product/1493017537myprod.jpg
           Name: Roses
           Quantity: 0
           Total Price: 0.00
D/SUCCESS: SELLER: 
           Seller Image: http://www.example.com/upload/userimage/1492766252IMG_20150325_174836~3.jpg
           Seller Name: Somnath Pal
           Seller Id: 3
```

Comment: So may be I'm incorrectly inserting the values in both Header and Child model class?

Comment: I tried but I got `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1` error in Adapter.

Comment: Logcat link: https://www.hastebin.com/renonuvura.nginx
Adapter link: https://www.hastebin.com/ojaniduqig.java
The error starts in the Adapter's getView() line `ChildModel model = arrayList.get(position).getChildList().get(position);`

Comment: can you please attach adapter code with this answer. I can't access your link may be my browser blocked it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142590/discussion-between-codeassasins-and-ferdous-ahamed).